# Swift - Code using closure to find sum of two numbers with the given code

Tags: swift, closures

//Write a program using two `Int` `numbers(num1 and num2)` and returns sum of those numbers//

given and disabled code:

```
import Foundation//given and disabled

// Write your code here.(I have to write my code here so that it gives 10 is 5 5 is given as input at run time)

 //my code 
let closure: (Int,Int) -> (Int) = {
return $0 + $1
}

//below code is given code and disabled.

let fileName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["OUTPUT_PATH"]!
FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: fileName, contents: nil, attributes: nil)

let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: fileName)!
guard let number1 = Int((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!)

else { fatalError("Bad input") }

guard let number2 = Int((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!)

else { fatalError("Bad input") }

let res = let closure(number1: number1, number2: number2)

fileHandle.write(String(res).data(using: .utf8)!)

fileHandle.write("\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
```

now when I write my code it is giving compile error in disabled code . Please help.

Comment: Check that your Comment sign are given properly.

Comment: #Torongo yes comments are given properly !!

Comment: `let res = let closure(number1: number1, number2: number2)`, this line is completely wrong

Comment: The code you're showing us doesn't match the code you're describing. You need to show us exactly the code you're trying to run. The code shown does not have the bottom code disabled, however you claim that it is.

Inside that bottom code is the strange `let res = let closure(...`
But without seeing the actual code you're trying to run, it is difficult to assist you with why something is going wrong.

Comment: this probelm is given by the Hackerrank tutorial and this code is disabled we cannot edit it .

Comment: #christopherdrum  - i have added my code

Comment: Did you try to change the line I pointed out?

Comment: Joakim Danielson - i can not edit the disabled code

Answer (score 1):

You should use closure like this,

```
let res = closure(number1, number2)
```